# Problem with slide show in Javascript. Slide index does't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to create a slideshow with an active dot while a slide is visible. Unfortunately when I use slideIndex-1 or slideIndex+1 the console says it's undefined. When I use SlideIndex in the console it indicates the number of the slideshow...But due to +1 and -1 which doesn't work, I'm not able to make an active dot. The data is fetched from the WP REST API.The dots are part of the template.

```
let slideIndex = 1;

function showAbout(a) {
console.log(a), lookingForData = !1, a.forEach(showData)
showSlides(slideIndex)
setInterval(function(){
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    slideIndex++;
    console.log(slideIndex);
}, 5000);

}

showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
slides[i].style.display = "none";  
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: Does `slides.length == dots.length`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  well...slides.length is 3 but when I write slides. length == dots.length in the console, I get 3 in the circle and 9! when I tried to console.log dots I get an array of 9 I have no clue why...in HTML I created only 3 dots :P anyway the slide show goes on but it doesn't toggle active dot :(

Comment: when I console.log (dots[i]); it clearly indicates me only 3 spans indicated in HTML...

Comment: Not sure I follow, but if `slides.length > dots.length` you will get an error at `dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";`